# Getting exception while sending a mail using javax mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

Below are the methods which I am using to send an email

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    final String fromEmail = "abc@gmail.com"; //requires valid gmail id
            final String password = "123456"; // correct password for gmail id
            final String toEmail = "xyz@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com"; 

            System.out.println("TLSEmail Start");
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); 
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); 

            Authenticator auth = new Authenticator() {

                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(fromEmail, password);
                }
            };
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);


    sendEmail(session, toEmail,"TLSEmail Testing Subject", "TLSEmail Testing Body");
    }

     public static void sendEmail(Session session, String toEmail, String subject, String body){
            try
            {
              MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
              //set message headers
              msg.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
              msg.addHeader("format", "flowed");
              msg.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");



              String content = getContent();


              msg.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
              msg.setContent(content.toString(), "text/html");

              msg.setSentDate(new Date());

              msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
              System.out.println("Message is ready");
              Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
              transport.connect();
              Transport.send(msg);  

              System.out.println("EMail Sent Successfully!!");
              transport.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

And this is the exception which I suddenly I started getting

```
 javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
      nested exception is:
        javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1999)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:709)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
        at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
        at com.sharique.mail.util.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:45)
        at com.sharique.main.TestMain.main(TestMain.java:38)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:543)
        at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.startTLS(SocketFetcher.java:480)
        at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1994)
        ... 6 more
    Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
        ... 17 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
        ... 23 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat Apr 04 20:45:55 IST 2015
        at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(Unknown Source)
        at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(Unknown Source)
        ... 27 more
```

Code was working fine without any errors, but just few minutes ago it started giving me the above exception. I didn't change the code, so how it is coming I don't know.  Please let me know of how to resolve this.

Comment: I've just started receiving the same error in my program that is trying to send e-mail via smtp.gmail.com.

Comment: Is there a problem from gmail side?

Comment: It seems so, I've just tested TLS authentication and SSL one, both give me the same error...

Comment: Changing my systems date to yesterday's date, it works fine then... I think there is some from there side...as mentioned in error
java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat Apr 04 20:45:55 IST 2015
So that port might be expired or some issue is ther

Comment: Unfortunately I can't just change the time on the server, I need the proper time for the database and other services...

Comment: I just changed it in my local system...but yes, can't change it in server

Answer (score 1):

the solution is add that line props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

Comment: I tried this one also, but this one doesn't works too... it gives below exception then

com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 587; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Comment: that code is working for me. try ir
this.pass="xxx";
   this.user="xxx@gmail.com";
   this.from = "xxx@gmail.com";
   this.nombre="NOMBRE";
   this.host="smtp.gmail.com";
   
   props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
   props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
   props.put("mail.smtp.host",host );
         props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.gmail.com");

   
   props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

Answer (score 0):

The exception clearly states what is causing it.
The certificate of your mail server seems to have expired, try accessing the server using a browser and check its certificate or try getting any page on the server using wget, you should receive a certificate error.

```
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check failed
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(Unknown Source)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateExpiredException: NotAfter: Sat Apr 04 20:45:55 IST 2015
    at sun.security.x509.CertificateValidity.valid(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifyTimestamp(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(Unknown Source)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: mail server in the sense??
I am just using simple java code and calling from main...so which server you are talking about??
Am not using any server as of now...but yes when I changed my system date to yesterday's date..it started working

Comment: he is talking about smtp.gmail.com, but when I query `echo | openssl s_client -connect smtp.gmail.com:465 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates` I get `notBefore=Feb 18 10:19:56 2015 GMT
notAfter=Dec 31 00:00:00 2015 GMT` so that seems to be in order.

Comment: My bad I didn't notice you are using gmail smtp.

Comment: so what shud I do now??
Suggest me the solution

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue as well. (Was even showing the same "Not After" message and same time as yours). After changing some configurations around, it started working again, however, I went back to my original configuration and it worked. I believe this was a hiccup in Gmail, which they have since fixed. Have you tried using port 465? That's the port I'm using which is working for me.

Also, here is my config that seems to be sending emails without the exception (This is config in my grails application, but you should be able to port these over to your Java code):

```
    grails.mail.host = "smtp.gmail.com"
    grails.mail.port = 465
    grails.mail.username = "xxxx@gmail.com"
    grails.mail.password = "xxxxxxx"
    grails.mail.props = ["mail.smtp.auth":"true",
                         "mail.smtp.socketFactory.port":"465",
                         "mail.smtp.socketFactory.class":"javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory",
                         "mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback":"false"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of my app begin to send mail again automatically without any change in the code...

Comment: Mine has just started working back, no changes on my side as well

Comment: Mine has started working too...I think there must be some issue with google which they resolved it...